# How to create user in amazon-cognito using boto3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create user using python3.x and boto3 but end up with facing some issues

I've tried using "admin_create_user" even id didn't worked for me

```
import boto3
aws_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', 
    region_name = CONFIG["cognito"]["region"]
)
response = aws_client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId = CONFIG["cognito"]["pool_id"],
    Username = email, 
    UserAttributes = [
        {"Name": "first_name", "Value": first_name},
        {"Name": "last_name", "Value": last_name},
        { "Name": "email_verified", "Value": "true" }
    ],
    DesiredDeliveryMediums = ['EMAIL']
)
```

[Error facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE8U2.png)

Comment: The error says it all. You haven't passed access key and secret key anywhere and you don't have it saved on your machine in awscli.

Answer (score 6):

- I think you didn't pass the configuration. First install the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

`pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

- Then type below command in your terminal,

`aws configure`

- Provide your details correctly,

```sh
AWS Access Key ID [****************6GOW]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************BHOD]: 
Default region name [us-east-1]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

Try this and you can also view your credentials in below paths.

```sh
sudo cat ~/.aws/credentials

[default]
aws_access_key_id = ******7MVXLBPHW66GOW
aws_secret_access_key = wKtT*****UqN1sO/1Pfn+BCrvNst*****695BHOD
```

```sh
sudo cat ~/.aws/config

[default]
region = us-east-1
```

or you can view all those in one place by `aws configure list` command,

[image]

Comment: he's trying to create a user pool through boto3...